# What does this structure mean in powershell: ${c:a.txt}

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell. What does this structure mean in powershell: ${c:a.txt}

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [Powershell Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell#Scripting):

> According to the variable syntax, if the path to a file is enclosed in braces preceded by a dollar sign (as in ${C:\foo.txt}), it refers to the contents of the file. If it is used as an L-value, anything assigned to it will be written to the file. When used as an R-value, it will be read from the file. If an object is assigned, it is serialized before storing it.